# 12.04 -- ruby1.8 missing dependencies

Tags: 12.04, ruby

I just built a new 12.04 ubuntu box and tried to install puppet package. This failed because it could not load ruby1.8. After some fiddling around I tracked the issue down to the fact that the libreadline5 package is no longer available. libreadline installs version six but libruby1.8 is looking for a package called libreadline5.

For various boring reasons I am *stuck* with 12.04 and puppet 2.7 (don't ask ;)

Not sure how to proceed from here?